# Sorting Object over key value

Tags: java, sorting

I have a ArrayList which contains Objects of CricketLiveScore

```
  CricketLiveScore{
     String homeAbbrevation;
   }

   List myList=new ArrayList<CricketLiveScore>();
   CricketLiveScore c1=new CricketLiveScore();
   c1.setHomeAbbrevation("IND vs PAK");
   CricketLiveScore c2=new CricketLiveScore();
   c2.setHomeAbbrevation("SRI vs NWZ");
   CricketLiveScore c3=new CricketLiveScore();
   c3.setHomeAbbrevation("AUS vs BAN");
   CricketLiveScore c4=new CricketLiveScore();
   c4.setHomeAbbrevation("NWZ vs IND");

   list.add(c1);
   list.add(c2);
   list.add(c3);
   list.add(c4);
```

I need to sort this Arraylist based in Object with value IND in home abbrevation
Can someone help on this so that i need a list to be sorted and show the output to be containing values with IND first.

Comment: What language are you using?  Most languages would let you just "list.Sort();" and use the default comparer.  How should the individual CricketLiveScore's be compared?

Comment: i am doing this in java .i need to right my own comparator

Comment: you need to implement a `Comparator`... are you a csk fan? BTW :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class CricketLiveScoreComparator implements Comparator<CricketLiveScore> {
    @Override
    public int compare(CricketLiveScore c1, CricketLiveScore c2) {
        return c1.getHomeAbbrevation().compareTo(c2.getHomeAbbrevation());
    }
}
```

And then call a sort operation:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new CricketLiveScoreComparator());
```

Comment: its sorting the value based on Alphabets i need a value with IND to be appear first in the list

Comment: then compare c1.getHomeAbbrevation().indexOf("IND") and c2.getHomeAbbrevation().indexOf("IND")

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class CricketSort implements Comparator<CricketLiveScore> {

    String countryOnTop;

    public CricketSort(String countryOnTop) {
        this.countryOnTop = countryOnTop;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(CricketLiveScore o1, CricketLiveScore o2) {
        if (o1.homeAbbrevation.contains(countryOnTop)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o2.homeAbbrevation.contains(countryOnTop)){
            return 1;
        }
        return o1.homeAbbrevation.compareTo(o2.homeAbbrevation);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ....stuff
        Collections.sort(scoreList, new CricketSort("IND"));
    }

}
```

Should work.

Comment: Above code is helpfull but needs to change this code to                                   class CricketSort implements Comparator<CricketLiveScore> {

 String countryOnTop;

 public CricketSort(String countryOnTop) {
  this.countryOnTop = countryOnTop;
 }

 @Override
 public int compare(CricketLiveScore o1, CricketLiveScore o2) {
  if (o1.homeAbbrevation.contains(countryOnTop)) {
   return -1;
  }
  if (o2.homeAbbrevation.contains(countryOnTop)) {
   return 1;
  }
  return o1.homeAbbrevation.compareTo(o2.homeAbbrevation);
 }

}

Answer (score 0):

you need a custom comparator, example here: http://java67.blogspot.de/2012/10/how-to-sort-object-in-java-comparator-comparable-example.html

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.vogella.com/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/

Basically you implement the Comparator interface in your data type and override the compare method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! got my own comparator to do this

```
      class CricketSort implements Comparator<CricketLiveScore> 
     { 
        String countryOnTop; 

         public CricketSort(String countryOnTop) { 
                this.countryOnTop = countryOnTop;
       }

      @Override 
      public int compare(CricketLiveScore o1, CricketLiveScore o2) { 
             if (o1.homeAbbrevation.contains(countryOnTop)) {
                  return -1; 
                  } 
             if (o2.homeAbbrevation.contains(countryOnTop)) { 
                  return 1; 
                  } 
           return o1.homeAbbrevation.compareTo(o2.homeAbbrevation);
             } 
         }

    }
```

its working perfectly for me